# How can take screenshot of new tab once its loaded completly in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
 @Test
public void testHeaderlinks() throws IOException {

    homePage=new HomePage();

    homePage.ClickmenuHolidays();
    homePage.Clickmenuattraction();
    
    
    homePage.Clickmenuhotdeal();
    String originalHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
  
    for(String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        if (!handle.equals(originalHandle)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
           
            driver.close();
        }
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(originalHandle);
}

public static void Takescreenshot(String filename) throws IOException {
    File file= ((TakesScreenshot))driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(file,new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\POMMabuhayFinal\\src\\main\\java\\Screnshots\\"+filename+".jpg"));
}
```

In my code i am click hyperlinks in new tab and close those tabs (closing all tabs after all hyperlinks clicks)

My question is how can i take screenshot of opened tabs( i wanna take all new tabs which are open)

Answer (score 0):

Use [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) to wait for tab/page load and then call your *Takescreenshot* method while you iterate tabs

```
@Test
    public void testHeaderlinks() throws IOException {
    
        homePage=new HomePage();    
        homePage.ClickmenuHolidays();
        homePage.Clickmenuattraction();        
        homePage.Clickmenuhotdeal();

        String originalHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

        int count = 1;
        for(String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            if (!handle.equals(originalHandle)) {
            // Initialize WebDriverWait with 15 secs wait timeout or expected wait timeout
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(myDriver, 15);
            // Wait for page to load
            wait.until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) myDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete"));
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            // Take screenshot of your current tab
            Takescreenshot("tabImage" + String.valueOf(count)) // You can use your own imageName
            driver.close();
            count++;
            }
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(originalHandle);
    }
    
    public static void Takescreenshot(String filename) throws IOException {
        File file= ((TakesScreenshot))driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(file,new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\POMMabuhayFinal\\src\\main\\java\\Screnshots\\"+filename+".jpg"));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Try this

```
public void TakeScreenShot()
    {
        try
        {
            string text = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\screenshots\\";
            if (!Directory.Exists(text))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(text);
            }
            if (Directory.Exists(text))
            {
                string text2 = text + XYZ+ ".jpeg";
                if (File.Exists(text2))
                {
                    File.Delete(text2);
                }
                ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(text2, ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```